# ufw (firewall) cant see active forward rules

Tags: ufw

I have a working port forward on my firewall (ufw). I can enable and disable the rule - and it works.

What I dont understand is, that the rule cannot be seen when doing:

```
ufw status
```

That command only show open port on the firewall itself.

My question is how can I see all rules on the firewall (also forward rules)?

Comment: ufw is just a front end for iptables. you can see all the iptables rules with `sudo iptables -xvnL` and `sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL`.

Comment: Ty for help, give an answer and I will mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL works very well!

```
sudo iptables -t nat -xvnL
```

Comment: @David - there is no other answer for the OP to accept - this answer is based on a comment.